# Python: Regex: find pattern + space that can be anywhere

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that allows me to find substrings following this pattern: `12345/123`: `'\d{5}/\d{3}'`.

I would also like to find substrings that follow the same pattern but with a whitespace that can be anywhere (except at beginning and end). Here are all the possibilities:

```
1 2345/123
12 345/123
123 45/123
1234 5/123
12345 /123
12345/ 123
12345/1 23
12345/12 3
```

Is there a simple way to do this with a unique regex?
I currently have a regex for each possibility (`'\d\s\d{4}/\d{3}'`, `'\d{2}\s\d{3}/\d{3}'`...), but it's not good practice.

Example:

String I have:

```
'THIS IS 50325/654 A TEST STRING 56 968/325 THIS IS A 65646 TEST 46546/ 564 STRING THIS 259 65/456 IS A TEST 54654/65 4 STRING'
```

Matches I would like to obtain: `['50325/654', '46546/ 564', '259 65/456', '54654/65 4']`

EDIT: 
Some more info:

- there is only one space and it will ultimately be removed
- there are many other numbers in the real data, so removing all the spaces is unfortunately not an option. Example: JLMREL 1515 25/15 115 RMK 46546/ 564 ==> One match 46546/ 564

Comment: if you just need the numbers couldn't you strip out every space then run the regex?

Comment: Only a single space is permitted? Are the spaces significant?

Comment: with your edit, will there ever be a case where the string has the proper number of numbers but too many spaces, ex: `123 45/123`?

Comment: From what I get, it's always 8 digits, 1 space and 1 bar, right?

Comment: @JudismarArpiniJunior yes that's it, and the bar is always at the 6th or 7th position

Comment: @depperm I don't really understand your question, your example is part of the possibilities I detailed

Answer (score 1):

You can try of OR "|" Operation in regex with multiple conditions

```
re.findall('\d{2,} \d{2,}/\d{3,} | \d{2,}/\d{3,} | \d{2,}/\d{1,} \d{1,}',a)
```

outL

```
[' 50325/654 ', '56 968/325 ', '259 65/456 ', ' 54654/65 4']
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, but I'm trying to find a simpler and more elegant way to do this without having to write every possibility

Comment: @EliseB , your problem (doing that without the basic union/or operator) does not have a solution via regular expression/finite automaton, just like some problems can't be solved by a computer/an algorithm. This is actually the correct answer, I say that as a regular expression writer, and not as a computer programmer. You can always write a Python function to do the job in other ways, which includes building the "ugly" regexp from scratch into a variable.

For instance, if you had 1000 digits, it would be a good idea to write a function that builds the solution for you.

Comment: I might actually write an answer explaining this in detail (when I have the time) if no one else does. It is important to understand the limitation of our means of computing, be that of an algorithm or a regexp/finite automaton.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to remove every space then run the regex.

```
import re

s='THIS IS 50325/654 A TEST STRING 56 968/325 THIS IS A 65646 TEST 46546/ 564 STRING THIS 259 65/456 IS A TEST 54654/65 4 STRING'
t=s.replace(' ','')

print(re.findall('\d{5}/\d{3}',t))
#['50325/654', '56968/325', '46546/564', '25965/456', '54654/654']
```

With the edit I believe if you modify your regex to `(?:\D)\d{5}/\d{3}(?!\d)` it will only get patterns that don't have an extra number at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will serve your purposes nicely.

\d((\d|\s){5})/(\d{3})|(\d{5}/(\d|\s){4})

So it either captures One digit, and then five more characters which are spaces or digits, then captures a /, then captures three digits, or it captures five digits, then a /, then 4 characters which are either spaces or digits.

It's really hard designing regexs without the data on hand to look at and check it against, as I'm not sure if my regex will work 100% of the time.

Also, I ran you're test string against it, my regex also captured 56 968/325 ontop of the other things you wanted to capture, I'm not sure if you want that however in your original possibilities list, you have a very similar looking value 12 345/123 so I assumed you were mistaken and forgot it.

Comment: I should mention, this regex won't capture anything without a space, hence if you want it to capture inputs without spaces, you can append |\d{5}/\d{3} to the regex in my answer.

Comment: This regex will also capture `1___5/1_3` (with underscores instead of spaces). Excluding more than one whitespace makes this ugly.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. It's a struggle to make it work otherwise. Seems like you managed it though :)

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat cheating as I use a regular expression with lookahead to verify the format 
 `digit{5}/digit{3}`, then verify that there is at most one whitespace left and right of the `/` and then match an arbitrary number of digits and whitespace:

```
\b(?:(?:(?=[\d\s]{6})(?=\d*\s\d*\/\d{3}\b))(\d*\s*\d*)\/(\d{3})|(?:\d{5}\/(?=[\d\s]{4}\b)(\d*\s*\d*)))\b
```

This is not much better than simply enumerating the whitespace in all positions, sorry.

*Edit*: Fixed the regexp to be a bit simpler and to allow floating matches against example string.

( [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/gODhra/2) )